# Socket in ASP with MSWINSOCK.winsock.1

Tags: sockets, asp-classic

I want to establish a socket in classic asp with "MSWINSOCK.Winsock.1" but when I run the following error

Server object error 'ASP 0177: 800401f3'

Server.CreateObject Failed

Anyone know what can be?, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this "socket" component, but the error is a generic error meaning that most likely you haven't registered the ActiveX (COM) component that "brings" the MSWINSOCK.Winsock.1 class. 
You need to "install" the component.